# Create room with unity networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, online-game

hi and firstly sry for my english ...
i newly start creating a multiplayer game with unity
i download unity master server and facilitator from [here](https://unity3d.com/master-server) and run them in my own server for creating an online multiplayer turn-base game.
when someone creating a room and other players join to that room, if the person who created the room, leave game or dc, other players will kick from room. is there any way to handle this problem?
something like reconnect? or create room in server?

Comment: I believe what you are after goes a long way. you probably need to implement something. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

For creating room i will recommend you [**Unity Network Lobby**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkLobbyManager.html)

> The NetworkLobbyManager is a specialized type of NetworkManager that
>   provides a multiplayer lobby before entering the main play scene of
>   the game.

Unity also provides an asset for [**Lobby manager**](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41836) which is easy to use. For its implementation i'll recommend you this [**Tut**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jklWlm5v21k).